# c++ pass parameters to thread as reference not working

Tags: c++

I wrote a code that create thread and send to him parameters as reference, but I get an red underline under the function name like I cant call it. Someone know what went wrong in my code

my code:

```
#include "getPrimes.h"

void getPrimes(const int& begin, const int& end, std::vector<int>& primes)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = begin; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if (i > 1)
        {
            for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) 
            {
                if (i % j != 0) 
                {
                    primes.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

std::vector<int> getPrimes(const int& begin, const int& end)
{
    std::vector<int> vector;
    std::thread thread(getPrimes, std::ref(begin), std::ref(end), std::ref(vector)); // I get the red underline here
}
```

the error I get

> [image]

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there is really no reason to be passing `int` values by `const` reference; just take them by value. Primitive types, _especially_ `int`s, generally fit into registers -- as opposed to references which forces indirection and may be difficult to optimize due to aliasing concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `getPrimes` is overloaded, you'll need to help the compiler with the overload resolution.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> getPrimes(const int& begin, const int& end) {
    std::vector<int> vector;
    std::thread thread(      // see static_cast below:
        static_cast<void(*)(const int&, const int&, std::vector<int>&)>(getPrimes),
        std::cref(begin), std::cref(end), std::ref(vector));
    // ...
    thread.join();
    return vector;
}
```

A simplified example:

```
void foo(int) {}
void foo(int, int) {}

int main() {
    // auto fp = foo; // same problem - which foo should fp point at?

    // same solution:
    auto fp = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(foo);
}
```

Comment: Yup. The "no instance of ... matches the argument list" error sounds like "you can't pass that parameter type", but frequently it just means, "I'm not sure which function you meant to call".